# why in c program prints then going to main?

Tags: c, recursion, static-variables

Why does program go to printf instruction however before this we call main function it should jump to main without executing the next instruction.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    static int i = 5;
    if (--i) {
        main();
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: What system is this running on? How many bytes (what range) has your `int`? -- Please consider that `(--i)` gets 0 at some points, and then `main()` returns. You might want to insert another `printf()` before the call. -- Anyway, `main()` must not be called recursively.

Comment: The variable `i` is static. So first you make recursive calls to `main` until `i` becomes zero, then the stack unwinds and each of the recursive calls goes to the `printf("%d, i)` statement, where `i` is zero at that point. Thus you see each recursive call to main printing `"0"` with the exception of the final one where `if(--i)` was false.

Comment: Because eventually `main` returns and then the computer does the next instruction.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `i` is static. So first you make recursive calls to `main` until `i` becomes zero, then the stack unwinds and each of the recursive calls goes to the `printf("%d, i)` statement, where `i` is zero at that point. Thus you see each recursive call to main printing "0" with the exception of the final one where `if(--i)` was false.

To illustrate this, when `i` finally reaches the value 0 your stack looks something like this

```
main()
main()
main()
main()
main()
```

Then the stack begins to unwind, and each of the `main()` calls returns to where it was (except at the top of the stack where `if (--i)` is false). At that point `printf("%d", i);` occurs and `0` is printed because `i` is static.

As mentioned in comments it generally isn't a good idea to call `main` recursively.